# how to avoid using javac -cp

Tags: java, jar, javac

I have a Java class which uses a `.jar` file.

Every time that I want to compile this class, I have to do something like `javac -cp ".:myJar.jar" myClass.java` and every time that I want to execute it, I have to do the similar thing but with `java` instead of `javac`.

Is there a way to avoid doing this?

I know that I could put this jar file into my class path but I don't want to do that. I don't neither want to do a maven projet.

Comment: The way to avoid it is to use a build tool (e.g. Maven, Gradle, etc.) and/or an IDE (e.g IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.) and let them handle building your project for you. At runtime, some options include using a `Class-Path` entry in the manifest file or creating a fat/uber jar file.

Comment: @Slaw the problem is that this a school project and my professor is gonna run it with java, not with any other tools or ides

Comment: If this is merely about convenience then you may have to just deal with specifying `-cp` in school assignments; at least for development you could create a script or, if using Java 9+, make use of `@file` arguments. Otherwise, your professor should be able to tell you what is acceptable regarding the use of external libraries in your assignment.

Comment: Does your professor like to make their life difficult? Just tell them to use an IDE.

Comment: If you get tired of typing `javac -cp ".:myJar.jar" myClass.java`, create a command script to run that for you (e.g. `.bat` if Windows, `.sh` if Linux). Then you just type the name of the script to run it, e.g. if you created a `x.bat`, simply typing `x<enter>` could compile and run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from using an IDE, taking advantage of all its super useful features when developing the program, and then submit just the source code and associated jars to the professor.

Advantages of using IDE that your professor don't need:

- Syntax color-coded editors with **auto-complete**.
- Built-in display of **javadoc**, so you know what all the built-in Java methods do, and how they work.
- Instant high-lighting of syntax errors.
- Never having to compile the code, since IDE always keeps the code compiled.
- Easy single-button execution of the program when you want to run it.
- **Debugger**. Very important feature when your code is not working as you intended.
- ... more ...